# How to add provision profile to device ios 7

Tags: iphone

I upgrade iphone to io7 and download xcode 5 , in organizer I add Provision for xocde and device but only added provision ditribute but add develope provision. please support me , Thanks.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Can you make your question clearer as I cannot understand your problem

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure your device is added in Device list at [Member Center of developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action). If not, add your device UDID;
2. Choose your Provisioning Profile in profile list and click Edit. Make sure that your device is added in list. If there is no your device, add it;
3. Download this profile and install it on your device via Xcode organizer (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks very much , i was add and success full

Comment: Did not realize that devices are not always automatically added to the provisioning profiles. No. 2 in the list saved me a lot of time! Thanks!